# Regular Expression to Extract a HTML Drop Down Tag- Classic ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I am using following Classic ASP code to extract contents from one of the webpage.

That webpage has one selectbox, what i want to do is display that select box only in the reponse, so not sure what should i change here `strPattern = "<select>(.*?)<\/select>"`

**HTML Dropdown code which i need to be accessed**

```
<select onchange="change_option('SELECT___MC-TRIMC350___56',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___MC-TRIMC350___56" class=" PIN_1373378891415_hazClick">
<option value="634">1 GAL [$64.99]</option>
<option value="629" class=" PIN_1373378891415_hazClick">5 GAL PAIL [$144.99]</option>
<option value="637">54 GAL DRUM [$2,225.00]</option>
</select>
```

**Classic asp Code to read the page Title, i want it to change so that select box is displayed as it is**

```
Dim strURL, objXMLHTTP, objXML, strContents
Dim objRegExp, strHTML, strPattern, colMatches, strTitle

strURL= "http://abc.com/testhtm" 


Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
'Or if this doesn't work then try :
'Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False

objXMLHTTP.Send

strContents = objXMLHTTP.ResponseText

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

Set objRegExp = New RegExp

strPattern = "<select>(.*?)<\/select>"

objRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True

Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strContents)

If colMatches.Count > 0 then
    strTitle = objMatches(0).Value
Else
    strTitle = ""
End If

Set objRegExp = Nothing

Response.write(strTitle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<select.*>[\w\W]*<\/select>`

I'm not sure if `.` to captures newlines in Classic ASP, so I opted for `\w\W` instead.  You need the `.*` between `<select` and `>` to skip past the html attributes (`onchange`, etc.)

UPDATE:
You have an error in your code.  You never set or declared `objMatches`.  You should use `colMatches` instead.

```
If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
    strTitle = colMatches(0).Value
Else
    strTitle = ""
End If
```